# How to prevent calling onLayout() method multiple times?

Tags: android, html, layout, webview

I'm working on my custom `WebView` where I load previously prepared `HTML`. I put the method which loads the `HTML` to the `@Overrided` `onLayout()` method but as far as I know it is called when the `view` should assign a size and position to all of its children. That's why when I add multiple `WebView`'s to the app they are flashing. Is there any other method which I can override to prevent loading my `HTML` many times?

Comment: Better if you add some code here. Do you extend the `WebView` class ? if yes, you can directly call something like `this.loadData()`.

Comment: Hi soommy12,you can overwrite ```shouldOverrideUrlLoading()``` method and  ```onPageStarted()``` method.Did you want load WebView once?